# Expression Error Key didn't Match Any Rows

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to get today's current date and format it to yymmdd because my table name change daily. e.g. MICRINFO210616 and tomorrow it will be MICRINFO210617

When I run thecode below  I get the following error:

```
Expression.Error: The key didn't match any rows in the table.
Key=
    Schema=dbo
    Item=MICRINFO210617
Table=[Table]
```

code:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("TEST", "TEST"),
    formattedDate = Date.ToText(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()), "yyMMdd"),
    combine = "MICRINFO" & formattedDate,
    dbo_MICRINFO210616 = Source{[Schema="dbo", Item=combine]}[Data]
in
    dbo_MICRINFO210616
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the account you're using has at least read permissions (to the new table).
2. Check if the structure of both tables is the same (same number of columns, same datatype).